# iTunes playlist copier

Tags: python, file, xml

When you own an Android device and want your iTunes playlist to be copied over onto it, what do you do?

What if your playlist hits something in the region of 20GB+ ? Well, I am sure I could've paid for a tool, to do this for me and keep things in sync, but I wanted to challenge myself into writing something in Python to resolve it.

I tried dragging and dropping the files on the playlist onto the phone via Android Device Manager and often found it would just hang. This is what I ended up with:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import os
from shutil import copyfile
import urllib

srcfile = "/path/to/playlist.xml"
dst = '/path/to/destination';
overwrite = 0

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse(srcfile)
songs = tree.findall('/dict/dict/dict/string')

# Run through all the found elements
for song in songs:
    # Is this element a file?
    if song.text[0:7] == "file://":

        # Grab everything after file://
        myfile = urllib.unquote(song.text[7:])

        # Grab the filename without the path
        basefile = os.path.basename(myfile)

        # Grab the last dirname
        dirname = myfile.split('/')[-2]

        # If the dir does not exist on the destination, create it
        if not os.path.exists(dst+dirname):
            os.mkdir(dst+dirname)

        # Create the final filename
        dstFile = dst + dirname + '/' + basefile

        # If the file exists and we have chosen to not overwrite it, dont copy the file
        if os.path.exists(dstFile) and not overwrite:
            print "Skipping " + myfile
        else:
            copyfile(myfile, dst + dirname + '/' + basefile)
            print "Copying " + myfile

print "Finished...."
```

I have found a bug in it when copying over bands or songs with UTF-8 names in it e.g. Fantômas. Because the UTF-8 elements are encoded in the Playlist XML the names do not match the directory so I need to fix that. Have kept a copy on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/catharsisjelly/fe7505cc33436ee4da71), so if you want a copy go grab/comment/whatever. I'm new to Python so any feedback is welcome on better ways to do things.

Comment: Any feedback is good, I'm new to python so any improvements welcome, I'll add this into the post

Comment: @Catharsis Have you considered reading about UTF-8 support in Python? I found [this page in the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) that has a lot of information about encoding.

Comment: @Phrancis I have yes but I'm not sure if that will help as they are encoded in the XML (probably as XML entities). This bug should be easy to fix, just not got round to it yet :)

Comment: For those interested the UTF8 bug was because the url's for the files were url encoded e.g. %2C. This was resolved with the use of `decode` in `urllib`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`overwrite` would be better as `True` or `False`.

Since each file is treated independently, you should define a function to make the independence obvious.

To split and join path components, use `os.path.split()` and `os.path.join()` instead of doing your own string analysis.  The interface is slightly nicer, and it also ensures that there won't be missing or extra `/` separators.

If you reorder the conditionals, you could reduce the number of `os.path.exists()` tests in the don't-overwrite case, where the destination file already exists.

Print `'Copying filename'` *before* copying the file, so that if the copying fails, you'll see which file it failed on.  Print `"Finished."` instead of `"Finished...."`, because ellipses imply that the job is incomplete.

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def copy_song(url, dest, overwrite=False):
    if not url.startswith('file://'):
        return

    orig_path = urllib.unquote(url[len('file://'):])
    orig_dirname, basename = os.path.split(orig_path)
    dest_dirname = os.path.join(dest, orig_dirname)
    dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dirname, basename)

    if not overwrite and os.path.exists(dest_path):
        print 'Skipping ' + orig_path
    else:
        if not os.path.exists(dest_dirname):
            os.mkdir(dest_dirname)
        print 'Copying ' + orig_path
        copyfile(orig_path, dest_path)


playlist = "/path/to/playlist.xml"
dest = '/path/to/destination';

playlist_xml = ElementTree.parse(playlist)
for song in playlist_xml.findall('/dict/dict/dict/string'):
    copy_song(song.text, dest)
print 'Finished.'
```

Comment: `orig_dirname` instead of `orig_dir_name`? `basename` not `base_name`? The standard library functions are `copyfile` `mkdir` `startswith`... would it be fitting to name this function `copysong` not  `copy_song`? Your `dest=` line doesn't need a semi-colon. `playlist=` uses double quotes inconsistent with all other strings. It's weird that it silently skips songs which don't start with 'file://', but reports skipping no-overwrite songs. Perhaps move the startswith test out, so copy_song isn't called for things which aren't songs? `url[len('file://'):]` could be `url.lstrip('file://')`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is really nice, and I could even say I learnt something reading this (`song.text[0:7]`), but it could be improved in places:

---

Python's official style guide: PEP8, dictates that variables not be named like `dstFile` but rather, `dst_file`. (*So on, for the rest of your variables named unaccordingly to PEP8*)

---

You should add some whitespace between your variable addition in places (`dst+dirname`), into `dst + dir_name`. (*fixed variable names too*)

---

> ```
> dstFile = dst + dirname + '/' + basefile
>
> if os.path.exists(dstFile) and not overwrite:
>     print "Skipping " + myfile
> else:
>     copyfile(myfile, dst + dirname + '/' + basefile)
>     print "Copying " + myfile
> ```

You declare `dstFile` as such, and then proceed to remake `dstFile` in the `else` statement.

Perhaps; `copyfile(my_file, dst_file)` (*fixed variable names too*) would be a better option.

Answer (score 4):

`song.text[0:7] == "file://"` looks like a job for [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

---

`dst + dirname` is computed in different place, it is probably worth just using a variable for this.

This is also relevant for `dst + dirname + '/' + basefile`.

Answer (score 3):

1. For UTF-8 encoding, you can either use Python 3.x, which has built-in UTF-8 encoding, or you can put `#coding: utf-8` at the top of your script.
2. I'm going to answer one thing on your "wishlist", the better progress bar. If you want a better progress bar, I'd do something like the below.

   ```
   for index, song in enumerate(songs):
       ...

       print "Copying file {0}, {1} of {2} files.".format(
           index, song, len(songs)
       )
   ```
3. If you want reusability for this, I'd recommend doing either of the two options.

   1. Creating a command-line utility, e.g, command prompt arguments and such.
   2. Creating a reusable function that can be imported and run with arguments.
4. Finally, you don't need comments above all those variable declarations. Preferably, you could give the variables more descriptive names, that describe what the variables do, without the need for comments.

Comment: Thanks for the input, all the comments were just to help me understand what I was doing but your right by saying my variables should be more descriptive, thank you for your input

Comment: A [`# coding: utf-8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) comment just declares that the source code is to be interpreted as UTF-8. That will make zero difference here, since the source code is pure ASCII.

Comment: @200_success Ah I see now. Maybe it's an issue with the XML library itself?